# Accessing member attributes of a class when we the member attribute's name is stored in another variable

Tags: python, syntax, instance-variables

We are facing a problem in accessing member attributes of a class when we the member attribute name is stored in another variable. For example : We have a class A, which has member attributes is var1, var2, var2, and upto var 100. From another class, we are trying to access var67, the name of attribute we want to access ( i.e. var67) is stored in a different variable x, as a string ("var67")(this x is generated from a different function). So from the value of x how can we access var67 attribute as we just can't do A.x . Please guide us any short approach other than building a method in class A to access variables in such case. Thanks!

```
MyClass: 
variable = "blah" 
def function(self): 
    print("This is a message inside the class.") 
myobjectx = MyClass() 
x="variable" 
myobjectx.(getattr(MyClass(), x))
```

The last line will throw a syntax error

Comment: Are the variables of the same type? If yes then why not use an array?

Comment: _we_ ?? Who is that?

Comment: which language? Can you show the code?

Comment: hi tobi303@ edited the question and added the code.

Comment: Why the "C++" tag?

Answer (score 0):

In python you have the `getattr` builtin function:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a67 = 10
x = "a67"
print(getattr(A(), x))
```

Here you have a [live example](https://repl.it/repls/AccurateQuintessentialNakedmolerat)

Comment: Thanks for your help, but my question here is related to non-static variables.. I mean when how do we solve the below problem..
class MyClass:
    variable = "blah"

    def function(self):
        print("This is a message inside the class.")

myobjectx = MyClass()
x="variable"
myobjectx.(getattr(MyClass(), x))

The last line will throw a syntax error.

Comment: Got the answer :
getattr(myobjectx, x)()

Comment: @RahulYadav, then you wanted to call a method from the class, not access one attribute (even if you can access them with getattr too)